# Can ArcGIS Pro read the labels in shapefiles created in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile

Can ArcGIS Pro read the label placement, label formatting and colors in shapefiles created in QGIS?

Comment: Nope. Shapefiles don't have an inherent symbology, you need to provide a `.qml` for shapefiles styled in QGIS, but Arc doesn't know how to deal with `.qml`.

Comment: It can't as far as I know. The OGC standard for styles is SLD and  QGIS can export SLD. Shapefiles topped up with SLD do work for example with GeoServer  but unfortunately ArcGIS desktop does not utilize SLD. ArcGIS server does support SLD so ESRI knows how to do it if they wish. There are free conversion utilities from ESRI styles into SLD and native QGIS styles but not another way round.